# Lxd preventing 18.04-18,10 upgrade in WSL

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, 18.10, lxd

Because lxs is now only installed from the snap store, and I have some problem with the snap store, my `do-release-upgrade` won't complete. How do I tell apt to stop trying to install lxd so it can finish?

```
balter@little-d:/etc/update-manager$ sudo apt clean
balter@little-d:/etc/update-manager$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lxd:
 lxd depends on lxd-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.1); however:
  Version of lxd-client on system is 1:0.4.

dpkg: error processing package lxd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.131ubuntu15) ...
Setting up open-iscsi (2.0.874-5ubuntu9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lxd-client:
 lxd-client depends on lxd (>= 1:0.4); however:
  Version of lxd on system is 3.0.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.1.

dpkg: error processing package lxd-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (239-7ubuntu10.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.4-2) ...
Setting up finalrd (3) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/finalrd.service → /lib/systemd/system/finalrd.service.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.131ubuntu15) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lxd
 lxd-client
balter@little-d:/etc/update-manager$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lxd : Depends: lxd-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 1:0.4 is installed
 lxd-client : Depends: lxd (>= 1:0.4) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
balter@little-d:/etc/update-manager$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libuv1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  lxd
The following packages will be upgraded:
  lxd
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 11.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 20.1 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 lxd all 1:0.4 [11.1 kB]
Fetched 11.1 kB in 0s (25.6 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 28554 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/lxd_1%3a0.4_all.deb ...
=> Installing the LXD snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
===> Aborting at user request
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/lxd_1%3a0.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 new lxd package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/lxd_1%3a0.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
balter@little-d:/etc/update-manager$
```

[image]

Comment: Couple ways you can go. Easiest might be to fix you snap store problem so you can uninstall the lxd deb.Or you can use apt-pinning. Or you can downgrade lxd-client. Or other options.

Comment: I tried using `apt-mark hold` but it still wouldn't ignore it. I eventually manually edited `/var/lib/dpkg/status` to remove reference to those packages. Hopefully no unwanted side effects. I guess I can work on the store now. I don't think it would have been possible before since `apt` was basically hobbled.